# How to decode h264 stream

Tags: c++, opencv, codec

I searched a lot but I can't find a decent library to solve to my problem. I receive a h264 stream from the network, and I want to decode it *from memory* and display it in real time. Something like this pseudocode below:

```
cv::Mat frame;
while (true)
{
    if (newDataArrived)
    {
        void* h264Buffer; // address with current h264 stream
        size_t h264BufferSize; // size of the stream
        LibraryINeed::UpdateFrame(frame, h264Buffer, h264BufferSize); // !?
    }
    ...
    imshow("display", frame); // show most recent frame
}
```

Is there any library that provides this functionality?

Comment: umm... Here you go: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=83127

Comment: Also, did you try the [cisco](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) library?

Comment: I will try libav. It's sad there aren't easy to use C++ wrappers like the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe `ffmpeg` https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial

Comment: You should be able to leverage GStreamer and opencv's VideoCapture to this end. GStreamer offers the [h264parse](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoparsersbad/h264parse.html?gi-language=c) element.

Comment: note: libav was a fork of ffmpeg. ffmpeg's libraries (not its CLI) have always been called libav* (libavformat, etc). the fork has been dying down for a while now. you'd best pick ffmpeg since it receives the most effort for improvements and maintenance.